# Prevent javascript from going out of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there any way I can prevent javascript from dropping an error if I try to go into a non existing array index?

Example: `array[-1]` would return error and eventually break all my code. How can I let it just return 'undefined' and let my script go on? I can implement an if statement before checking the array (so that if the index is minor than zero or major than the array size it would skip it) but this would be very tedious!

this is my code:

```
if (grid[j-1][i])
n++;
if (grid[j+1][i])
n++;
if (grid[j][i+1])
n++;
if (grid[j][i-1])
n++;
if (grid[j-1][i-1])
n++;
if (grid[j+1][i+1])
n++;
if (grid[j-1][i+1])
n++;
if (grid[j+1][i-1])
n++;
```

It is inside of two loops which both sees J and I starting from zero. I don't want to change them and neither writing another if statement (as you can see, there are already too much of them!). Is there any solution?

Thanks!

Comment: You do know you can write all those `if`s with one `if`, right?

Comment: @gdoron - I don't think it could (at least not neatly), since more than one rule could apply, and with an `if`, `n` would only be incremented once. A loop would work, but then you'd end up with 4 nested loops.

Comment: @KarlNicoll how bout `n+= !!grid[j-1][i] + !!grid[j+1][i] + ...`

Comment: @d_inevitable. +1. I got a feeling it could be even a lot simpler than that.

Comment: @d_inevitable - Nice, but I wouldn't exactly call it "maintainer friendly" :P

Comment: There is something wrong with your algorithm if it can run out of the defined indexes. You should rethink it.

Comment: kay - I don't want to change the loops. I just have a big grid and want to check each cells and its neighbours. Going off border would produce error...

Comment: what does the double ! means??

Comment: @d_inevitable - thanks a lot for that! I also need to put all of these if statements away. How exactly that works? What does "!!" mean?

Comment: `!!` coerces to boolean. One `!` coerces to boolean while negating the value; the second doubly-negates.

Comment: @Saturnix `!!x` "casts" a value to a boolean. It's a double negation. For a single negation see e.g. http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript

Comment: @Saturnix sentinel cells around your grid would'nt be an option?

Comment: Is there a reason why `grid[j][i]` is not on the list?

Comment: A wild guess: it's homework and you are supposed to program Conway's Game of Life?

Comment: @d_inevitable - yep. All the code posted is inside of another if statement which checks if grid[j][i] is 1 or 0. That's why adding another if statement for error handling would be insane...

Comment: @kay - no it's not a homework, just for fun. Yes, it's the game of life :)

Comment: @kay, would try with sentinel cells if there are no faster solutions

Comment: @Saturnix good, I put it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the measures of your grid, you can put "sentinel cells" around it.

If you add a -1st index to an array `x`, it does not count to `x.length`. Putting an additional last element into the list would increment `x.length`.

I daresay using sentinel cells combined with the arithmetic counting algorithms mentioned by  d_inevitable would be the fastest solution, since it would not involve branches. You even can omit the `!!` because `true` will evaluate to 1 and `false` to 0 in an equalization.

#### Update:

**Do not** use index -1. Its an awful lot slower that normal array indexes. See http://jsperf.com/index-1.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `||`, which muffles errors, e.g.:

```
(grid[j-1] || [])[i] || false
```

(I haven't tested this, but it should work)

Edit: updated based on am not i am's suggestion

Comment: I think the idea is that `grid[-1][i]` will throw an error because you can't access `[i]` on `undefined`. The `||` won't help with that.

Comment: ...you'd need to do something more like this... `(grid[-1] || [])[i]`

Comment: Yep, except that you should be able to get rid of the `|| false`, since when the empty array is used, the `[i]` will give `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

A less tedious way while still using ifs would be checking the first index if it's defined:

```
if (typeof grid[j-1] != "undefined" && grid[j-1][i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function to do the checks:

```
function getArrayValue(arr,key) {
    if( key < 0 || key >= arr.length) return null;
    return arr[key];
}
```

But really you should be avoiding out-of-bounds keys anyway.

Answer (score 0):

How about this for your solution?

```
for (dj = -1; dj <= 1; ++dj) {
  for (di = -1; di <= 1; ++di) {
    if ((dj || di) && grid[j+dj] && grid[j+dj][i+di]) {
        n++;
    }
  }
}
```

If you refactor all those `if`s into a single loop like the above, then having to do the extra conditional is not so bad.

Comment: Why was this -1? I see nothing wrong with it. @downvoter: Please explain why MarkReed's answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
for(m = Math.max(j-1,0) ; m <= Math.min(j+1,grid.length-1) ; m++)
  for (p = Math.max(i-1,0) ; p <= Math.min(i+1, grid[m].length-1) ; p++)
     n += !(m == j && p == i) && !!grid[m][p];
```

Comment: Is it your intention to use `n` as the `grid[m]` index as well as the main `n += ...`  counter? I'm not understanding it.

Comment: @amnotiam, ok it should make sense more now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: One more thing, I think you have your `min` and `max` reversed.